# Calculate Days Prior and Return a Date?

Tags: formula

I have a custom date field called "payment_due_date__c" and a formula field called "reminder_date__c".  I want to display a date in the reminder date field equal to **5 business days prior** (not including holidays) to the value in the payment due date field.  Business days are defined as Monday - Friday

I did some searching and found other solutions that return the number of days, but I want to return a date value instead.

I have this which is close, but not quiet there:

```
CASE(
 MOD( payment_due_date__c- DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
  3, payment_due_date__c- 2 - 2,
  4, payment_due_date__c- 2 - 3,
  5, payment_due_date__c- 2 - 4,
  6, payment_due_date__c- 1 -5,
  payment_due_date__c- 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are only trying to consider weekends in your calculation and not public holidays. If that is the case, then the following formula should do the trick.

```
CASE( 
    MOD( WEEKDAY(Payment_Due_Date__c), 7 ), 
    0, Payment_Due_Date__c - 5, 
    6, Payment_Due_Date__c - 4, 
    Payment_Due_Date__c - 6 
)
```

The above should provide the following result:
When Payment Due Date = 1/20/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/14/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/21/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/15/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/22/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/16/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/23/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/17/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/24/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/18/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/25/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/21/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/26/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/21/2019
When Payment Due Date = 1/27/2019, then Reminder Date = 1/21/2019

Notice the last 3 results are the same due to the payment due date being on a weekend.

Comment: There seems to be a problem @aayush-k if the payment due date is 1/24/2019, 5 prior business days would be 1/17/2019, not 1/18/2019

Comment: That should be an easy fix. I was assuming by 5 business days, you mean the payment due date will be included in counting the 5 days. You can try the following - `CASE(
 MOD( WEEKDAY(Payment_Due_Date__c), 7 ),
  0, Payment_Due_Date__c - 5,
  1, Payment_Due_Date__c - 6,
  Payment_Due_Date__c - 7
)`